# What causes Razor templates to reject classes that depend on System.Windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a generic model:

```
public abstract class MyModel<T> 
    where T: MyBase, new()
{ ... }
```

and I have a specific model, where Foo inherits from MyBase:

```
public class MySpecificModel : MyModel<Foo>
{ ... }
```

and in my Razor template, I want to instantiate an instance of MySpecificModel:

```
@{
    var test = new MySpecificModel();
}
```

If MyBase inherits from System.Windows.DependencyObject (because it happens to be a WPF ViewModel class that I need to reuse) I get an exception when the Razor template is compiled saying that I'm missing a reference to WindowsBase.dll, even though I have that reference in my project. I tried adding @using System.Windows to my template, but Razor won't recognize the namespace at all.

To work around this issue, I changed the code as follows:

```
public abstract class MyModel 
{
    protected abstract MyBase myBase { get; }
    ... 
}

public class MySpecificModel : MyModel
{
    private Foo _myBase;
    protected override MyBase myBase
    {
        get
        {
            if (_myBase == null)
                _myBase = new Foo();
            return _myBase;
        }
    }
    ... 
}
```

Inside of MyModel I have to change any "new T()" to "myBase" in order to access the Foo object. This approach works perfectly, but it's a lot more work for the MySpecificModel class, which I'm going to have many variations of for different sub-classes of MyBase.

So, why does the first approach fail while the second succeeds? It's not just the use of generics, because if MyBase doesn't inherit from a WindowsBase class there's no problem. I think it has to do with where the Foo object is being constructed, and something Razor is doing to prevent the use of any WPF classes. But I can't find any documentation about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET generates a new anonymous assembly from the *.aspx/*.ascx/*.master/*.cshtml files that then references your web application's assembly, the generated classes are stored in the `ASP.` namespace. This assembly is generated at runtime when the first request is made to your web application.

This new assembly only additionally references a few other assemblies (`System.Web.dll`, etc) and not the `System.Windows.xxx` assemblies as you noticed.

Because ASP.NET is generating a new assembly based on exposed types from `System.Windows` it needs to reference that assembly directly, which it won't - whereas when it works with types that children of types derived from System.Windows types (i.e. your working example) it works because it isn't interfacing with System.Windows directly.

Comment: Cool, that makes a lot of sense. Do you know if there is a way to add to the assemblies that the generated code will reference?

Comment: Use the `<compilation> <assemblies> <add /> ` element in web.config: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx